# Delegate is nil in a Swift program

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, protocols

I'm practising how to communicate between two view controllers using protocol and delegate (in the xCode background even when I'm using protocol in my project I get the same problem, Delegate is nil), but the problem after setting everything it shows me that my delegate is nil and the sender VC does not send any data since the delegate is nil.

I have confirmed to the protocol and I have set the receiver VC as the delegate, but still can not see where the problem is.

The Protocol

```
protocol theCommunicationsStructionProtocol{

func dataToTransmit(Data: String)

}
```

The Sender VC

```
class TheSenderVC{

var delegate: theCommunicationsStructionProtocol?

func lookingForDelegate(){


self.delegate?.dataToTransmit(Data: "Data has been sent")

 }
}
```

The Receiver VC

```
class TheReceiverVc1: theCommunicationsStructionProtocol{
var TheSenderVCObj = TheSenderVC()

func delegateLuncher(){

TheSenderVCObj.delegate = self
}

func dataToTransmit(Data: String) {
print("from VC1: \(Data)")
 }

}
```

calling delegateLuncher() to set the delegate in the receiver VC

```
TheSenderVC().lookingForDelegate()
```

calling lookingForDelegate() from the sender VC to look for the 
delegate and send it the data

```
TheReceiverVc1().delegateLuncher()
```

Note: I have tried accessing the delegate from the receiver VC using this way:

```
class TheReceiverVc1: theCommunicationsStructionProtocol{
 var TheSenderVCObj: TheSenderVC?

func delegateLuncher(){

self.TheSenderVCObj?.delegate = self
}

func dataToTransmit(Data: String) {
print("from VC1: \(Data)")
 }

}
```

but I still getting the same problem:

> delegate is nil

Comment: start protocol names with capital letters

Comment: It will help you in the future if you follow some Swift conventions; variables and properties should start with a lower case letter. Class, struct and protocol names should start with a capital letter.

Comment: The problem is this line: `var TheSenderVCObj = TheSenderVC()`. This is _not_ the instance whose delegate you want to set, so you are setting the delegate of the wrong object. Meanwhile the delegate of the _real_ TheSenderVC remains `nil`. Please read: http://www.programmingios.net/dont-make-a-new-instance-by-mistake/

Answer (score 7):

Finally, I found the solution!
the problem is I was making instances of the TheSenderVC, instead of takling to the original TheSenderVC.
when I was making an object (an instance) of TheSenderVC the problem occurred! instead I have to access the original TheSenderVC, which means I have to use static :)

here is the old delegate set up

```
var delegate: theCommunicationsStructionProtocol?
```

from TheSenderVC

here is the new delegate set up

```
static var delegate: theCommunicationsStructionProtocol?
```

therefore the

```
func lookingForDelegate(){


self.delegate?.dataToTransmit(Data: "Data has been sent")

}
```

will be changed to

```
static func lookingForDelegate(){


self.delegate?.dataToTransmit(Data: "Data has been sent")

}
```

since now it includes a static property (delegate)

on the other hand, the The ReceiverVC1 should be changed from:

```
class TheReceiverVc1: theCommunicationsStructionProtocol{
var TheSenderVCObj = TheSenderVC()

func delegateLuncher(){

TheSenderVCObj.delegate = self
}

func dataToTransmit(Data: String) {
print("from VC1: \(Data)")
   }

  }
```

to:

```
class TheReceiverVc1: theCommunicationsStructionProtocol{


func delegateLuncher(){

TheSenderVC.delegate = self
}

func dataToTransmit(Data: String) {
print("from VC1: \(Data)")
}

}
```

accessing the delegate from the original TheSenderVC()

Comment: `static var delegate: theCommunicationsStructionProtocol?` working fine, thank you....

Answer (score 0):

Where are you create the reference of **TheSenderVCObj**

replace  **var TheSenderVCObj: TheSenderVC?**  to  **var TheSenderVCObj = TheSenderVC()**

let try below code:

```
class TheReceiverVc1: theCommunicationsStructionProtocol{
 var TheSenderVCObj = TheSenderVC()

func delegateLuncher(){

self.TheSenderVCObj?.delegate = self
}

func dataToTransmit(Data: String) {
print("from VC1: \(Data)")
 }

}
```

your TheSenderVCObj also nil according to your code.

**NOTE: use proper naming conventions.**

Comment: convert  var TheSenderVCObj: TheSenderVC? to var TheSenderVCObj = TheSenderVCObj().

Comment: this is wrong  var TheSenderVCObj = TheSenderVCObj(), it should be var TheSenderVCObj = TheSenderVC(),  TheSenderVC() is the name of the sender class, but your code does not solve the problem, however I appreciate your respond

Comment: no problem Garg, but even if I make it TheSenderVCObj = TheSenderVCObj(), the delegate is still nil

Comment: can you share the demo project if you have any, i think we did something wrong in references part, may be created 2 references of TheSenderVC in which one have delegate and another does not. you can try at ur end as well.

Comment: I tested the object using init(){} and deinit{} in the sender class, and I found out that the object gets initialized then deinitialized and finally initialized again. I will try to find out the solution and let you know, thank you for your help

Answer (score -1):

Because the `TheReceiverVc1` was automatic deinit by `ARC`.
You need to save reference of the instance like that's:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    let theReceiverVc1: TheReceiverVc1 = TheReceiverVc1()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        theReceiverVc1.delegateLuncher()
    }
}
```

Also make sure when you using delegate set it as weak var:

```
weak var delegate: theCommunicationsStructionProtocol?
```

Comment: you are right, I found out by using init(){} and deninit{} that it initialized the object twice and then digitized it

Comment: Yes always you are using ‘TheReceiverVc1()’ you create a new instance.